# How can I configure Supervisor to use a variable for command directory?

Tags: laravel, environment-variables, queue, supervisord

I am using supervisor to watch my laravel queue and restart on failure. I followed the [instructions in laravels documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#supervisor-configuration) to install and configure the service. This configuration works correctly:

```
[program:notifications]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/project/artisan queue:work --queue=notifications --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=3
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/project/storage/logs/notifications-worker.log
stopwaitsecs=7200
```

My issue is that my web directory changes on each release. How can I configure the command to run in the newest release directory without having to update the configuration file on each release?

I was thinking that I could set a variable to the correct directory using `find`

```
find /var/www/html/project/releases/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | head -1
```

This returns the correct directory but I am unsure of how to go about setting this in the configuration file. I think that I can set the environment variable and then access it from the configuration like this:

```
PROJECT_PATH=$(find /var/www/html/project/releases/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | head -1)

[program:notifications]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php %(PROJECT_PATH)s/artisan queue:work --queue=notifications --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=3
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=%(PROJECT_PATH)s/storage/logs/notifications-worker.log
stopwaitsecs=7200
```

I am not sure how reliable this method is and am looking for some direction. Does anyone else use supervisor to monitor a queue in a dynamic web directory? If so how do you specify the directory and update that on each new release?

Comment: I'm not going to put this as an answer since it's not the method you are requesting, but could you programmatically update a symbolic link `current_version` to point to the proper directory each time a new release is published?  (e.g., `/var/www/html/current_version/artisan ...`)  Then your supervisor config would not need to be dynamic.

Comment: I think I understand. I currently have a symlink for `current -> /var/www/html/project/releases/public` and I reference `current` in my nginx site configuration file. Based on your suggestion it sounds like I should instead symlink to the base and then specify the `current/public` in my nginx site configuration?

Comment: That certainly sounds like it could be an option.  And using a single symlink as you suggest would be easiest to maintain down the road.

Comment: I've implemented this strategy and it is working. You should post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as accepted for this issue. Thank you!